# UIGestureRecognizer in UILabel subclass not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a subclass of `UILabel` that looks like this:

```
class GestureLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longPressGestureRecognizer:")))
    }

    deinit {
        gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
    }

    func longPressGestureRecognizer(sender: AnyObject) {                
        print("this is never called")
    }
}
```

but `longPressGestureRecognizer` is never called. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `userInteractionEnabled` is disabled on `UILabels` so you must manually enable it when adding gesture recognizers.

Make sure you set `self.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: I think it's good to mention `userInteractionEnabled` is `false` by default for `UILabel`.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I can't believe I forgot about that ;)